# SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer (after giving command node index in terminal)

Tags: redux

```
const redux = require('redux')
const createStore =redux.createStore
const BUY_CAKE= 'BUY_CAKE'

function buycake(){
       return
{type:BUY_CAKE,info:'First Redux Action'}}const initialState ={numOfCakes=10}

const reducer =(state=initialState,action)=>{switch(action.type){ case BUY_CAKE:return{ ...state,numOfCakes= state.numOfCakes -1}

        default: return state
    }
}

const store = createStore(reducer)console.log('Initial State', store.getstate())const unsubscribe=store.subscribe(()=> console.log('Updated State', store.getstate()))store.dispatch(buycake())store.dispatch(buycake())store.dispatch(buycake())unsubscribe()
```

Comment: Please correct the preformatted code snippets.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

numOfCakes:numOfCakes-1